# Raster resolution

Tags: raster, resolution

I have a climate model that has 8km resolution and I am not sure what it means, does it mean that every cell is showing an equivalent of 8 km in real life?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the model the 8km resolution would be the output from the model assigning that particular modelled value to a cell ~8km by ~8km.

As an example, the ECMWF atmospheric models are interpolated to approximately 0.1° or 9km grids.

https://www.ecmwf.int/en/forecasts/documentation-and-support